# Oracle invalid identifier in select query in WITH section

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

Why do I get an invalid identifier error in this query?

```sql
with
      select
           notif_set_code as notification_code
         , (
            select tab_to_string(
               cast(collect(
                  case
                     when area_type is not null then
                        count(*) || ' ' || area_type
                     else 'default'
                  end
               ) as t_varchar2_tab), ' ,')
            from my_table_2
            where notif_set_code = nsd.notification_code 
         ) areas
      from my_table nsd
...
```

It sayd `nsd.notification_code` is not a valid identifier.
Using `nsd.notif_set_code` works if it's not in a with clause!

Comment: That's not a correct syntax for a query with CTEs. It should take the form `WITH q1 as (SELECT ...), q2 as (SELECT ...) SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, there is no column called `notification_code` in nsd.  You seem to intend:

```
where notif_set_code = nsd.notif_set_code
```

Renaming the column in the `select` doesn't change anything (although rather confusingly MySQL seems to allow column aliases in subqueries but that is an anomaly).

However, you should really qualify *all* column references:

```
where my_table_2.notif_set_code = nsd.notif_set_code
```

Comment: If I name the column to `notification_code` then `where my_table_2.notif_set_code = nsd.notif_set_code` doesn't work for some reason! It complains on the `nsd.notif_set_code` as I said.